# Undefined value from input when i want set object property

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

i have defined model in c#, but i'm creating him in JS code like this ...

```
var m = { myModel : <%= JsonSerialize( new MyModel()) %> };
```

it's works ... my properties are actually set to null ...

next i need set properties by input value ...
for example:

```
<input type="text" id="name" />
<button type="button" id="btnRead" onclick="read()">Send</button>
```

JS:

```
function reloadGrid () {
   m.myModel.Name = $('#name').val();
}
```

models property is still null and browser alert me on error "Cannot set property 'Name' of undefined" ... but when i print in console value of my input like this ... value was printed correctly.

Comment: What do you expect of value to be when you use new MyModel()?

Comment: property in this model is defined like string .. so i need save input value to this property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the error, "Cannot set property 'Name' of undefined", this means the myModel property of the m object is undefined.

Make sure the m object is in scope of the reloadGrid() function, and that myModel is spelt correctly etc

Try the below (assuming this is an MVC app)

```js
function reloadGrid () {
        var m = { myModel : @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyModel())) };       
        m.myModel.Name = $('#name').val();
}
```

Comment: m is out of scope becouse is global variable whitch i used in other function